# Get value from int type of SharedPreferences to a String

Tags: java, android

I'm stuck with this, problem, I need to save a color from users choice via `SharedPreferences` and I did that with this code:

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        imgBtnDarkBlue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tvColorScheme.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                editor.putString("color", tvColorScheme.getTextColors().toString());
                editor.commit();
            }
        });

        imgBtnGreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tvColorScheme.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                editor.putInt("color", getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                editor.commit();
            }
        });

        imgBtnBlue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tvColorScheme.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                editor.putInt("color", getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
```

And retrieving it in another Activity:

```
int colorScheme = preferences.getInt("color", 0);
        if (colorScheme == 0) {
            imgViewColorScheme.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        } else {
            imgViewColorScheme.setBackgroundColor(colorScheme);
        }
```

Now I need to check which color has user selected and put it's value in String. How do I do that?

Comment: if you want to convert a int to string you can use `String.valueOf(intHere);`

Comment: you are using putString in one color and putInt in rest 2.. why?

Answer (score 0):

Print in the log first as

```
Log.d("somestring", ""+colorScheme );
```

Then try this way.

```
String.valueOf(colorScheme);
```

Comment: Yes but then how can I check which value is stored with "color" key?